# How to create a string of filenames separated by comma in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I am trying to create a string eg (file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt).
All these 3 files names are within a file.

```
ls file*.txt > lstfiles.txt

while read filename; do
  filename+=$line","
done <lstfiles.txt
```

This returns me with output:

```
file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt,
```

How can I find the last iteration of the loop so I dont add another comma at the end.

Required output:

```
file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt
```

Comment: all in one:  ls -1p file*.txt|xargs echo|sed 's/ /,/g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case I would rather get rid of the while loop and combine `sed`and `tr` commands like so:

```sh
sed -e '$ ! s/$/,/g' lstfiles.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

Where `sed` command replace each line endings execept the last one with a comma and `tr` command remove the linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [avoid using `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) though.

```
printf '%s,' file*.txt |
sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

assuming your `sed` recognizes `\n` to be a newline, and copes with input which doesn't have a final newline.